# jquery mobile app UI changes after I build through phonegap

Tags: jquery-mobile, phonegap-build

I developed mobile application using jquery mobile,when I run the html file mozilla and Internet explorer prompts me to activate "Active X control".Once I select Activate UI looks as expected otherwise javascript code is displayed on screen and UI is not proper.
I have build the App using phonegap UI has changed because I do not activate "active X control".

Please suggest me how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the answer to your problem. Since you are accessing this file which is located in your computer, IE by default disables ActiveX for safety as it can be used for malicious purposes as well. If your page link in the browser starts with `file://` then the browser will ask you to activate ActiveX. If you use a browser other than IE (Chrome, Firefox), I believe that you will not face this issue. To my knowledge, there is no other way apart from allowing ActiveX

If you want to greenlist the page, you can do so like this

1. Open Internet Explorer.
2. Go to Tools and then Internet Options.
3. Click Trusted sites and click Sites.
4. Enter your website name and then click add.

This should hopefully eliminate the ActiveX prompt.

Also, I would recommend that you do not use IE. Use the latest version of Chrome or Firefox or Microsoft Edge.

Once you upload this app into a production server, you will not face this issue. If you still use IE, then I wish you good luck.

[For your information](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/why-internet-explorer-block-activex#1TC=windows-7)